# How to check whether my Node.js create-react-app runs on localhost?

Tags: node.js, heroku, localhost, create-react-app

I try to check like this, but it crashes the app:

```
  let fbAppId
  if (location.hostname === "localhost" || location.hostname === "127.0.0.1")
    fbAppId = "402670860613108"
  else
    fbAppId = "2526636684068727"
```

I want to know when app runs on `Heroku` and when in localhost.

Comment: Is it in react or Node.js?

Comment: It is in React, a create-react-app

Answer (score 3):

Try to check it through `window.location.hostname` and it will work.

```
let fbAppId
if (window.location.hostname === "localhost" || window.location.hostname === "127.0.0.1")
    fbAppId = "402670860613108"
else
    fbAppId = "2526636684068727"
```